# Is there a way to get ‘Fuzzy Search’ in GNOME Shell’s Applications Screen?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, search

In the past starter/search apps like Synapse or Docky had the great feature fuzzy search for files, applications, folders and more. Unfortunately the search in GNOME Shell’s Applications Screen does not support it.
Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **bug report or feature request open** to add fuzzy search to GNOME Shell, please help if you can to get this helpful feature back to Ubuntu: [Application search algorithm (g_desktop_app_info_search()) should use fuzzy matching](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/1152)

**You can get [fuzzy search for APPS](https://gitlab.com/Czarlie/gnome-fuzzy-app-search)** (only) with the [Fuzzy App Search GNOME Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3956/gnome-fuzzy-app-search/). It is a great start, hopefully the fuzzy search feature will be expanded in the future (in whatever way).

**Source**: [OMG Article "add fuzzy search to GNOME Shell"](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/12/fuzzy-search-gnome-shell-extension)